# Firebase not found while it is installed Shopify app

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, shopify, shopify-app

I am developing a Shopify app in which I intend to use Firebase as my storage, I successfully installed it and I see the package in package.json `"firebase": "^9.5.0"` but when importing I get this error in the terminal `ERROR in ./conn.js ┃ Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'firebase'`
I tried the solutions in other similar questions but nothing worked, should I do something special to get Firebase working with Shopify?

Here is the code that I use the exact way in my React project and it works there

```
import firebase from 'firebase';

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "XXX",
    authDomain: "XXX",
    projectId: "XXX",
    storageBucket: "XXX",
    messagingSenderId: "XXX",
    appId: "XXX",
    measurementId: "XXX"  
});
const db=firebaseApp.firestore();

export default db;
```

Comment: Share the code snippet where you are facing this issue. It maybe because in firebase v9, the imports are tree-shaked.

Comment: Added to the post

Comment: Hi, Can you try ```const firebase = require("firebase/app");
require("firebase/firestore");``` instead of ```import firebase from 'firebase';``` and see if it works?

Comment: I tried, same error

Comment: Can you try installing firebase tools using ```npm -g install firebase-tools``` and check version using ```firebase --version```, can you also provide your package.json file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure to follow the steps as mentioned in the official documentation to [Add Firebase to your JavaScript project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup).

As mentioned in this document, you should be importing as below, for your version 9 SDK:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
```

However, if you are developing an app, you need to follow the guidelines from here:

1. Android - [Add Firebase to your Android project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)
2. iOS+ - [Add Firebase to your Apple project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup)